# geting only object name in php and the values separately separated by commas

Tags: php

i have a json format like so

```
{"January":1,"February":2,"March":3,"April":0,"May":0,"June":0,"July":0,"August":0,"September":0,"October":0,"November":0,"December":0}
```

i would like to have two arrays to be outputed somthing like this

```
arry1 = [January,February,March ...]
arry2 = [1,2,3...]
```

how can i do this without going through a substring function as that would be a longer method does php have any built in feature for this

Comment: `json_decode()`

Comment: what please expain futher

Comment: You want to decode the JSON into a PHP array right? use the function I mentioned

Comment: please read the question and what i want to achieve

Comment: I see, have you tried anything? post what you have tried in the question by editing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this would work for you:

```
<?php

// Put the json object into a variable
$jsonObject = '{"January":1,"February":2,"March":3,"April":0,"May":0,"June":0,"July":0,"August":0,"September":0,"October":0,"November":0,"December":0}';

// Decode the json object
$jsonDecodeValues= json_decode($jsonObject);

// Create an array for months and day numbers
$monthNameArray = array();
$monthNumberArray = array();

// Loop through the decoded values and add them to the month/number variables
foreach ($jsonDecodeValues as $jsonDecodeKey => $jsonDecodeValue) {
    $monthNameArray[] = $jsonDecodeKey;
    $monthNumberArray[] = $jsonDecodeValue ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a loop to separate the keys from the values.  php has functions that isolate the keys and values...

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/t8daH))

```
$json = '{"January":1,"February":2,"March":3,"April":0,"May":0,"June":0,"July":0,"August":0,"September":0,"October":0,"November":0,"December":0}';

$decoded = json_decode($json, true);  // decode as an array
$arry1 = array_keys($decoded);        // isolate the keys
$arry2 = array_values($decoded);      // isolate (and re-index) the values

echo "\$arry1: ";
var_export($arry1);
echo "\n---\n\$arry2: ";
var_export($arry2);
```

Output:

```
$arry1: array (
  0 => 'January',
  1 => 'February',
  2 => 'March',
  3 => 'April',
  4 => 'May',
  5 => 'June',
  6 => 'July',
  7 => 'August',
  8 => 'September',
  9 => 'October',
  10 => 'November',
  11 => 'December',
)
---
$arry2: array (
  0 => 1,
  1 => 2,
  2 => 3,
  3 => 0,
  4 => 0,
  5 => 0,
  6 => 0,
  7 => 0,
  8 => 0,
  9 => 0,
  10 => 0,
  11 => 0,
)
```